# Extract returning data from an angular promise

Tags: angularjs

Greetings to everyone.

I'm trying to get data returned from an $http on angular. I created a factory:

```
.factory('MyFactory', function($http, SKURL) {
    return {
        all: function(my_data) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: SKURL.url,
                data: "data=" + my_data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Then, in the controller, I write:

```
var n = MyFactory.all(my_data);
```

When I see console.log(n), I see the returned object is a promise: `Promise {$$state: Object}`. I see the data when I expand the object. But, when I try get n.$$state.value.data I get `undefined`. How can I get the data returned for the `$http` ?

Comment: try adding the `.then` part after wherever you are calling the `MyFactory.all(my_data)`. So `n.then(function(data){});`

Comment: I think you need to use .then(funtion(response){return response;}) You can see it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you controller, try the following instead:

```
var n;

MyFactory.all(my_data).then(function(response) {
    n = response.data;

    console.log(n); // this should print your data;

    // do something with 'n' here.
}, function(err) {
    // handle possible errors that occur when making the request.
});
```